# Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift4, uiimagepickercontroller

[image: edit with image for privacy]I'm getting this frustrating error and I have no clue what I'm doing wrong since the

> make photo works
>
> and choose from the library doesn't work

I'm using swift 4 and my code looks like this :

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

  var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self 
   }

      @objc func changeThePicture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Choose a photo from your gallery", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.changePicture()
    }))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Make a photo", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.openCamera()
    }))
    
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func changePicture() {
    self.checkPhotoLibraryPermission {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary) {
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func openCamera() {
    self.checkMakePhotoPermission {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func changePictureButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.changeThePicture(sender: sender)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("media")
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.chosenImage = pickedImage
        userProfilePic.imageView.image = pickedImage
        uploadImage(userImage: chosenImage) { (result) in
        }
    }
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

> media is printed only when I make a photo...but when I choose from library nothing happens I receive this error
>
> [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
> Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
> UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Comment: What is `checkPhotoLibraryPermission`?

Comment: checking PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() with completion handler

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you do logic (upload image) before image picker modal dismiss completely.

Change your method into this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("media")
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        dismiss(animated:true) { [weak self] in
            self?.chosenImage = pickedImage
            self?.userProfilePic.imageView.image = pickedImage
            self?.uploadImage(userImage: chosenImage) { (result) in
            }
        }
    } else {
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```